# moment.tz issue with setting a "Etc/GMT[+|-]HH:MM" timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I've been banging my head on this for over a day, gone into the source code, and this *looks* to be an issue with the awesome javascript moment.tz library:

Whenever I pass in a timezone identifier of "Etc/GMT*time-value*", the moment.tz object returned comes back with what I believe to be an format("Z") value as it is multiplied by -1.

Example:

```
var pacificTime = moment.tz("2016-09-29 21:00:00","America/Los_Angeles");
pacificTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z z");
```

output: "2016-09-29 21:00:00 -07:00 PDT"

All is as expected here.

Now, using the same time zone (GMT-7):

```
var GMT_minus_7 = moment.tz("2016-09-29 21:00:00","Etc/GMT-7");
GMT_minus_7.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z z");
```

output: "2016-09-29 21:00:00 **+07:00** GMT-7"

The bold faced value is always the negative value of what I believe it should be: Passing in "Etc/GMT+5" returns a "-5:00" value.

This is causing me a headache, as the web page I'm working with has records with date/time records an integer "GMT offset" value which I simply turn into "Etc/GMT" + *offset_value* and pass into moment.tz to do a time zone conversion.  I then need to do further manipulation on the value (adding days, displaying that "Z" formatted value, etc.) but this issue has impeded further work.

Is this a defect with moment.tz parsing the "Etc/GMT" timezone values, or am I missing something fundamental about time zone formatting?

Comment: I did a further test, and it appears to be a formatting bug in moment.tz; I ran the following test:

`GMT_minus_7.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z z")`

and got the response 

"2016-09-29 14:00:00 +00:00 UTC"

The UTC conversion correctly subtracted 7 hours from 21:00 to give 14:00.   So it appears that the formatting of the "Z" value may be incorrect for this use case.

Comment: WRT your comment - you called `.utc()`, so anything after that is going to be in UTC, which is `+00:00`.

Answer (score 2):

The identifiers in the IANA database such as `Etc/GMT-7` have their offset inverted *intentionally*.  This is part of the design of this style of identifier.  See [the note in Wikipedia on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area), and [in the tz database source itself](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2016g/etcetera#L36-L42).  (Basically, it stems from the need to be backwards compatible with older POSIX standards in certain environments.)

However, in the case of Moment.js, you do not need to use these at all if you are working with a fixed time zone offset.  In fact, you don't need the moment-timezone extension at all.

```
// the parseZone method will retain the offset provided
var a = moment.parseZone("2016-09-29 21:00:00 -07:00");

// or, you can set the offset explicitly like this:
var b = moment.utc("2016-09-29 21:00:00").utcOffset("-07:00", true);

// or like this if you prefer:
var c = moment.utc("2016-09-29 21:00:00").utcOffset(-7, true);
```

For `b` and `c`, note that the `true` parameter is required to retain the given local time.  Also note that I use `moment.utc(...)` to initially parse the string.  It would also work with just `moment(...)`, but then it's *possible* that a DST transition in the *local* time zone could interfere with the interim value.

Also, make sure you recognize that `America/Los_Angeles` alternates between -8 and -7 depending on whether DST is in effect or not.  That is why you would need moment-timezone to supply the rules for when to switch between offsets.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you very much!